# Templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compile Templates located in different files in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869373/how-to-compile-templates-located-in-different-files-in-c)

I want to make a class template with a member function template.

If I code it inline (where I declare it) it works fine, but if I want to code it outline (like the example bellow) I get a error that says "'Example ::func' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration"

```
template <typename T>
class Example {
public:

    template <typename F>
    void func(F &f);

};


template <typename T, typename F>
void Example<T>::func(F &f) {
    //My code
}
```

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the link, I've been looking for a good one to use in dupe closing, but I'm not sure that is the issue here.

Comment: The syntax for declaring templates inside templates in various permutations is inscrutable and nonsensical. As near as I can tell, it's a mass of special cases with no hard and fast rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may will want to make this function inline though, if it's in your header file.  Otherwise you could get duplicate symbol errors.

```
template <typename T> template <typename F>
void Example<T>::func(F &f) {
    //My code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct format for defining template members of template classes is as follows:

```
template <typename T> template <typename F>
void Example<T>::func(F &f) {
//My code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937653/c-templates-in-ubuntu-linux-cpp/5938060#5938060). I just answered a question on explicit instantiation of templates. You should be able to find LOTS more questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
template <typename F>
void Example<T>::func(F &f) {
    //My code
}
```

`Example` class has only one template parameter `T`.